# check whether redis queue is set or Map

Tags: redis

I want to check items present in queue from java so I tried this

```
public String getQueueItemCount(String queueName) {
    String status = "";
    Long queueItemCount = null;
    try {
        this.jedisPool = redisConfig.getJedisPool();
        Jedis jedis = this.jedisPool.getResource();
        if (jedis.exists(queueName)) {
            queueItemCount = jedis.llen(queueName);
            status = "Items in " + queueName + " queue are: [" + queueItemCount + "]";
            log.info(status);
        } else {
            status = "Queue " + queueName + " not exist!";
            log.info(status);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Exception while getting queue count for: " + queueName, e);
    }
    return status;
}
```

but this won't work for set as we need to use scard method to get count
I need one check that will give me which type of queue is set or Map.